# Finding relatives of the series $\varphi =\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{(2k)!}{(k+1)!k!2^{4k+3}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, catalan-numbers, golden-ratio, constants

Consider $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the *golden ratio*. Bellow are series $(3)$ and $(6)$ that represent $\varphi$
$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi &=\frac{1}{1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\cdots&(1)\\
\varphi &=\frac{2}{1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\cdots&(2)\\
\varphi &=\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{(2k)!}{(k+1)!k!2^{4k+3}}&(3)\\
\varphi &=\frac{5}{3}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\cdots&(4)\\
\varphi &=\frac{8}{5}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\cdots&(5)\\
\varphi &=\frac{13}{8}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{(2(k+1))!}{((k+1)+1)!(k+1)!2^{4(k+1)+3}}&(6)\\
\vdots&\\
\end{align*}
$$

When looking at the leading terms of $(3)$ and $(6)$  $\;\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{13}{8}$ respectively, one is tempted to conjecture that there are similar formulas to fill the holes in the above table.

I'd like to know if such family of formulas exist.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
Note that both formulas connect the Golden Ratio $\varphi$ to [Catalan Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number/)
$$
C_{k}=\frac{(2k)!}{(k+1)!k!}
$$
so for $(3)$ we have
$$
\varphi =\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{C_{k}}{2^{4k+3}}
$$
and for $(6)$ we have
$$
\varphi =\frac{13}{8}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{C_{k+1}}{2^{4(k+1)+3}}
$$
So, maybe this could be used, somehow, to find the other formulas.

Comment: FYI : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221584/how-many-infinite-series-representations-of-the-golden-ratio-are-in-existence

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/CatalanInPascal.shtml

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/goldenmeanseries/home/golden-mean-series-derivation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right. There is a family. A little experimentation shows that,

$$\varphi =\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{C_{k}}{2^{4k+3}}$$

$$\varphi =\frac{13}{2^3}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{C_{k+1}}{2^{4k+7}}$$

$$\varphi =\frac{207}{2^7}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+2}\frac{C_{k+2}}{2^{4k+11}}$$

$$\varphi =\frac{1657}{2^{10}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+3}\frac{C_{k+3}}{2^{4k+15}}$$

$$\varphi =\frac{53019}{2^{15}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+4}\frac{C_{k+4}}{2^{4k+19}}$$

and so on. Sorry, but the numerators of the fractions are not Fibonacci numbers. It seems hard to predict what they will be.

Comment: very nice, maybe the Fibonaccis are hidden somehow in those fractions... for example $207=3^{2}\cdot 23$.

Comment: The difference between consecutive fractions is of the form $\pm\frac{1}{2^a}$, except for the last one:
$$\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3}=\frac{13}{8}$$
$$\frac{13}{2^3}-\frac{1}{2^7}=\frac{207}{2^7}$$
$$\frac{207}{2^7}+\frac{1}{2^{10}}=\frac{1657}{2^{10}}$$
but now we have
$$\frac{1657}{2^{10}}-\frac{5}{2^{15}}=\frac{53019}{2^{15}}$$

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont: Interesting observation.

Answer (score 5):

Let us take the first term out of the summation in equation $(3)$.

$$\begin{align}
\varphi&=\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{C_k}{2^{4k+3}}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{8}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{C_k}{2^{4k+3}}\\
&=\frac{13}{8}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{C_{k+1}}{2^{4k+7}}\\
\end{align}$$

The result is equation $(6)$.
Iterating the same procedure gives all formulas listed in Tito Piezas' answer, so this family is obtained directly from equation $(3)$.

The general formula for the fractions is therefore
$$\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^N (-1)^{k}\frac{C_k}{2^{4k+3}}$$

Egyptian fraction versions of $(2)$, $(4)$ and $(6)$ are given by

$$\varphi=2-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(2^{k+2})}$$

$$\varphi=\frac{5}{3}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(2^{k+3})}$$

$$\varphi=\frac{13}{8}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(3·2^{k+2})}$$

and additional series involving Fibonacci numbers are given by

$$\varphi=\frac{34}{21}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(2^{k+4})}$$

$$\varphi=\frac{89}{55}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(5·2^{k+2})}$$

$$\varphi=\frac{233}{144}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(3·2^{k+3})}$$

$$\varphi=\frac{610}{377}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(7·2^{k+2})}$$

The general pattern is

> $$\varphi = \frac{F(2n+1)}{F(2n)}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{F(n2^{k+2})}$$

Alternatively, we can write formulas (1), (2), (4) and (5) as a linear combination of formulas (3) and (6), from relationships

$$1=5\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-4\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)$$

$$1=-3\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+4\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)$$

$$\frac{5}{3}=-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)$$

$$\frac{8}{5}=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{4}{5}\left(\frac{13}{8}\right)$$

After some algebra, the results are

> $$\begin{align}\varphi &= 1 + 3\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2k)!(4k+7)}{k!(k+2)!16^{k+1}}\tag{1}\\
> \\
> \varphi &= 2 - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2k)!(8k+13)}{k!(k+2)!16^{k+1}}\tag{2}\\
> \\
> \varphi &= \frac{5}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2k)!(4k+5)}{k!(k+2)!16^{k+1}}\tag{4}\\
> \\
> \varphi &= \frac{8}{5}+\frac{3}{5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2k)!}{k!(k+2)!16^{k+1}}\tag{5}
> \end{align}$$

Two observations: the procedure used has little to do with these particular fractions, similar results could be expected for any fraction; the simplest formula, (5), is obtained from a true interpolation, with both coefficients positive.

Since all these fractions lie between $1$ and $2$, we may take equations (1) and (2) as a basis and parameterize the family of approximations $\varphi\approx \frac{p}{q}$ according to

$$\frac{p}{q}=2\alpha+1(1-\alpha)=\alpha + 1$$

so the general equation may be written

$$\varphi=\frac{p}{q}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2k)!((3-5\alpha)4k+21-34\alpha)}{k!(k+2)!16^{k+1}}$$

where $\alpha=\dfrac{p}{q}-1$.

When $\dfrac{p}{q}=\dfrac{3}{2}$ then $\alpha=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and the multiplying polynomial $(12-20\alpha)k+21-34\alpha$ reduces to $(2k+4)=2(k+2)$. This cancels the largest factor of $(k+2)$! in the denominator and equation (3) is obtained.