# Looking for a proof of an interesting identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Working on a problem I have encountered an interesting identity:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k}\binom{n+2k}{k}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)^n,
$$
where $n$ is a non-negative integer number and $x$ is a real number with absolute value less than 1 (probably a similar expression is valid for arbitrary complex numbers $|z|<1$).

Is there any simple proof of this identity?

Comment: How/where did you meet this identity? Is the LHS just the Taylor series for the RHS?

Comment: Anything to do with a random walk? Why did you call this interesting, btw?

Comment: Reminiscent of the explicit form for [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html), hence they idea of enforcing the substitution $x=\sin\theta$ and applying the residue theorem looks like a promising one ;)

Comment: Or you may prove that both sides are the terms of an Appell / [Fibonacci sequence of polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciPolynomial.html).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Residue theorem is indeed a good idea ^^

Comment: Please post a link to your source of this identity. Others might find it useful too.

Comment: @Mathemagical Working on a problem I reduced a part of it to computation of the sum in question. I inserted the sum in *Mathematica* for $n=1$ and unexpectedly have got the respective closed form solution. Then I tried it for higher $n$'s and have concluded the general form. Is this the answer you have expected?

Comment: @user355705 Thanks. No, I mean what is the subject area. There is a very similar problem that appears in computing the distribution of hitting times of a random walk. I was wondering if your problem came up in stochastic processes as well.

Comment: @Mathemagical do might share a reference with us. im am very interested (this formula has also connections to bosonic Greens functions on a 1D tight binding chain, i would like to explore the connection to random walks)

Comment: @tired This is in regard to the hitting time of a random walk (more particularly, the probability generating function of the hitting time of the walk at the barrier x=1. Please see the equations 15,16, and 17 in the linked document. http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/RW.pdf  The details of the computation are not listed here, but they are shown in greater detail in Michael Steele's book, Stochastic Calculus and Financial applications (pages 8 and 9).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using

[$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_C\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}dz$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470099/a-golden-ratio-series-from-a-comic-book/1470255#1470255)  we get (integration contour is the unit cicrle)

$$
2\pi iS_n=\oint dz \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1+z)^{n+2k}x^{n+2k}}{z^{k+1}2^{n+2k}}=\oint dz \frac{(1+z)^n x^n}{z2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1+z)^{2k}x^{2k}}{2^{2k}z^k}=\\
4\frac{x^n}{2^n}\oint dz \underbrace{\frac{(1+z)^n}{4z-(1+z)^2x^2}}_{f(z)}
$$

for $|x|<1$ only we have just one pole of $f(z)$ inside the unit circle namely $z_0(x)=\frac2{x^2}-\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}-1$ , so

$$
S_n=4\frac{x^n}{2^n}\text{res}(f(z),z=z_0(x))=4\frac{x^n}{2^n}\left[ \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(2\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{ x^2}\right)^n\right]
$$

or

> $$
> S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{ x}\right)^n
> $$

Comment: Thanks Jack :-)

Comment: @tired: Thank you very much for the nice proof. It contains however a misprint. $4$ shall be replaced with $4^{1/n}$ in the denominator of the residue value. But probably simpler and more correctly were to write it just as $$\text{res}(f(z),z=z_0)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-x^2}} \left(2\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}\right)^n.$$

Comment: @user355705 you are absolutly right

Answer (score 2):

Extracting coefficients on the RHS we get the integral
(coefficient on $x^{n+2k}$)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+2k+1}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}  
\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z}\right)^n
\; dz.$$

Now we put $(1-\sqrt{1-z^2})/z = w$ so that $z = 2w/(1+w^2).$ This has
$w = \frac{1}{2} z + \cdots$ so the image in $w$ of the contour in $z$
can  be  deformed to  a  small  circle  enclosing  the origin  in  the
$w$-plane.  (Moreover  we see  that the  exponentiated term  starts at
$z^n$ which justifies the corresponding offset in the series.)  We get
$dz = 2/(1+w^2) - 4w^2/(1+w^2)^2 \; dw = 2(1-w^2)/(1+w^2)^2 \; dw.$ We
also have $1-z^2  = 1 - 4w^2/(1+w^2)^2 =  (1-w^2)^2/(1+w^2)^2.$ All of
this yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w^2)^{n+2k+1}}{2^{n+2k+1} w^{n+2k+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-w^2)/(1+w^2)} w^n \frac{2(1-w^2)}{(1+w^2)^2} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{n+2k}} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w^2)^{n+2k}}{w^{2k+1}} \; dw.$$

This evaluates by inspection to

$$\frac{1}{2^{n+2k}} [w^{2k}] (1+w^2)^{n+2k}
= \frac{1}{2^{n+2k}} [w^{k}] (1+w)^{n+2k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{n+2k}} {n+2k\choose k}$$

which is the claim.

Answer (score 1):

I plan to insert this approach into the next (2019) version of my notes.
The even powers of $\arcsin(x)$ all have a nice Maclaurin series (see eqs [(19),(20),(21),(22)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html)), and this can be seen as a side effect of the [Lagrange–Bürmann inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem). I am going to implement the same trick here, by computing the derivatives at the origin of the RHS (the opposite way has already been investigated by tired).

$$[x^m]\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)^n\right]=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})^n}{x^{n+m+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
where the integral is performed along a small circle enclosing the origin. What about enforcing the substitution $x=\sin z$? The sine function is holomorphic and injective in a neighbourhood of the origin, hence the RHS is simply converted into
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{(1-\cos z)^n}{\left(\sin z\right)^{n+m+1}}\,dz =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{2^n \sin^{2n}\frac{z}{2}}{2^{n+m+1}\sin^{n+m+1}\frac{z}{2}\cos^{n+m+1}\frac{z}{2}}\,dz$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{\tan^{n-m-1}z}{2^{m}\cos^{2m}z}\,dz=\frac{1}{2^{m+1}\pi i}\oint u^{n-m-1}(1+u^2)^{m-1}\,du$$
via $z\to 2z$ and $z\to\arctan u$. Now the RHS is trivially given by a binomial coefficient multiplied by $\frac{1}{2^m}$ (provided by $m\geq n$) and the claim is proved.